# how to read pound/hashtag symbol from java program arguments?

Tags: java

I have a program that requires reading several characters from the command line. One of which will always be #. However for a reason I don't know, if the input were say x 0 x # 0 8 0. it will only load x 0 x. I was wondering if # is has special properties in this case that cause it to quit loading? if so how can I load it from the args as it's character?

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong with your program if you don't show us your program.

Comment: If you are on a unix flavor system, the shell is probably taking the `#` as the start of a comment. (so escape the # with a \ )

Comment: I can confirm what @John3136 said. Escape the # with a \. eg: `java yourclass x 0 x \# 0 8 0`

Comment: The most common unix flavor systems today are the Mac and Linux. Are you using one of these?

Comment: crusty, probably not the responses you were looking for.  To use stackoverflow properly you need to ask questions appropriately, supplying the information people need to help you.  Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit or delete/resubmit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem working on a project and as @John3136 suggested using a backslash \ with # will solve your problem. It's a problem not only with ubuntu but also with MAC.